# placing a <p> beside a centered <h1>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

below is the code where it center everything inside. But now I just want to center the Title and append the date by not moving the Title to the left. The title have to remain in the middle with date appended behind. How can I achieve that?

```
<div class="row center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 style="display:inline;">Title</h1><p style="display:inline;"> 27th June 2014</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your css please. also, how is it related to bootstrap?

Comment: by looking at the class "col-md-12" then this is for bootstrap. And can't you see there is inline css style?

Comment: i have tried your html with bootstrap 3 and it did nothing, this is why i asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a trick, you can try:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <p>27th June 2014</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text-center .title {
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-center .title + p {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -5px 0 0 10px; /* adjust margin-top based on your line height */
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/tFOrJUP4g8Pr0LxLWN9w?p=preview

Since `col-md-12` has `position: relative` you can position `p` absolutely, and fix vertical alignment with negative margin (adjust for your line height).

Also instead of `.center` class you can use build in Bootstrap `.text-center` class.

Comment: Better than my solution!

Comment: @PokeItWithAStick Just a little, but the same principle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe re-organize a bit and put the date as a span inside the title:

```
<div class="row center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 id="title" >Title <span>27th June 2014</span></h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then your css could be something like:

```
#title {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}

#title span {
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twAU3/

Answer (score 0):

Not really a bootstrap answer (it may have inset classes to deal with this already)

but you could offset the date with a negative margin:

http://jsfiddle.net/9vXaj/

```
<div class="row center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Title</h1><span class="date"> 27th June 2014</span>
    </div>
</div>

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.center h1{
    display: inline;
}
```

In my example i changed the `p` to `span` as it is inline already but depends on the context of your HTML structure if a `p` would be more semantically correct (date doesn't feel like it needs a paragraph for me)